# Is there any advantage in running a universal motor on DC power?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

Since a universal motor can run on AC or DC, is there any advantage of using DC over AC?  If so, what chracteristics of the motor improves, if any.  What about noise levels?

Comment: One of the many advantages that spring immediately to mind is not having to make AC at times where all you have available is DC.

Comment: By the way, in China "AC servo" is mostpopular. Of course it's a BLDC with servo drive piwered from AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told in the 1970s that the Universial   motor runs better due to less sparking at the brushes .I tried this on a vacuum cleaner motor and a sewing machine motor and found that it was true .Bridge rectifiers suitable for mains were starting to become cheap .A Si bridge rectifier on 230VAC mains wastes about 1% so it is plausible that you are better off with DC .I did not use a filter cap because I was concerned about peak charging currents and did not want to give the motor 315VDC .The electro caps in my junk box in 1976 were not big enough being more suited for valve radios.These days you could do a simple boost PFC stage giving the motor fairly pure DC which can be bucked down for speed control .When the barefoot universial motor is stalled on its AC mains supply the resistance and the reactance of the windings add vectorialy to      limit the current .When the stalled motor is given DC it is just the resistance that is limiting current .This increased stall current issue makes the motor less idiot proof on DC unless some other form of current limiting is employed .The universial motors that I have mucked around with are two pole .This means that operation below about 3000rpm from a theory viewpoint wont be as smooth .I found that controlled DC gave much better low speed operation than the cheap orthodox triac controlled AC .

Comment: What about noise levels?  Does DC make for a quieter motor?

Comment: @ user148298 .I thought that it made less noise at low speeds .Remember this was when I was e teenager and did not have access to much test gear .

Comment: @user148298, whether or not DC motors make less noise has everything to do with the the design of the machine itself, but between the two options, DC is quieter because it eliminates mains hum. The new iteration of American submarines is reported to feature an all DC distribution system, and has inverters mounted to the motors where it is needed.

Comment: So I could I add a rectifier for my shopvac to make it quieter?

Comment: @user148298  The bridge rectifier will help the Hum but not the air noise .When this was applied to 1980s vacuum cleaners when I was a student there was a small noise reduction.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is better, for several reasons:

- reduced iron losses
- reduced brush temperature
- reduced motor size
- reduced noise
- increased lifetime

My source is [ST Application Note 422](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/38/51/d6/de/c1/73/43/9b/CD00003829.pdf/files/CD00003829.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003829.pdf). This is quite old but I believe the general conclusions and topologies are still relevant.

Comment: You mean I can get a quieter shop vac by adding a rectifier inline? Please make my day! Yay!

Comment: 100Hz / 120Hz noise is not the only noise source in a shop vac, there is also tremendous noise from the exhaust.

Comment: Yeah, but it is barely perceptible. Rigid has a foam muffler on the exhaust that helps.